# Permissions needed to edit content in XPM?

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, 2013-sp1

What permissions do I need do I need to grant a user for them to edit content in XPM?  The user in question has a disabled "Finish Editing" button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think for editing components in XPM you need Component Management right on the website publication security, then Write permissions on the folders where the components of the page are stored. 
For applying changes on pages such as insert/remove content, switch Page Template etc... you need Page Management right on the website publication security as well as Write permissions on the Structure Group security where the pages are stored.

What rights/permissions did you assign so far to the Group that the user is a part of?
Does the user see a Lock icon on the Page border and/or on Component Presentations borders?

Comment: I got it working.  I added the Segment Management right.  Is that needed?  It looks like it.

Comment: Wow that sounds weird, it should not be needed.

Comment: Adding *any* right might work if the user lacked Scope because the user or its group(s) had *no* rights for the content Publication. For what it's worth the Save Draft and Finish Editing and commands disable regularly in XPM as it saves Component changes or Publishes. After editing a field, click outside the field or Component Presentation and you'll notice Save Draft quickly enables and then disables. After Publishing, Finish Editing disables. If the user sees the Blue and Green (by default) borders or can actually edit text, then they already had enough authorization to edit the content. :-)

Comment: @MrSmith I wouldn't know what Segment Management rights are, but if the user can edit the content in the CME, then it can also edit it in XPM. Important thing to notice is that in XPM it needs to be able to acces (i.e. read) the Page and the Component, since it loads the Page first.

Comment: Segment Management rights are from Audience Manager and aren't used when editing in XPM.